# How do I aggregate(merge) multiple excel files by each sheet into one master file?

Tags: excel, merge

I was trying to combine multiple excel files (114 in total) and each has multiple sheets(4 in total) with exact same name like the examples below:

```
1. File A: Sheet Dog / Sheet Cat / Sheet Bird
2. File B: Sheet Dog / Sheet Cat / Sheet Bird
3. File C: Sheet Dog / Sheet Cat / Sheet Bird
4. File D: Sheet Dog / Sheet Cat / Sheet Bird
.
.
.
.
```

What I want to achieve is to merge all these files, and aggregate the data (merge vertically) by each sheet, Sheet Dog merge only with Sheet Dog, and sheet cat only with the cat ones. Eventually, get a master excel file with all the sheets merged.

I have tried `Get Data -> From File -> From Folder` but I am not getting anywhere and it seems not really what I want? I was wondering if there's any code or technics available that I can merge systematically? Thanks for the help, any suggestions are super appreciated.

---

I found this code on other answers and still struggling to customize it:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "C:\XXXX"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
            total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)

            GoTo exitFor:

        Next sheet

exitFor:
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
Sub MergeAcrossSheets()

End Sub
```

I have edited the `directory` to my folders that contain all the excel files, and I also created an XLSM `import-sheets.xlsm` in that same folder and put this macro code in the module, I then ran it but nothing happened. Can anyone point out what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes! Thanks for sharing, but I just tried to run that code but nothing happened. I am really new to VBA so don't know how to do the bug fixes

Comment: That code gives you a start. You'll need to adapt it to your specific requirements. SO isn't a free code writing service. Make an effort to understand what that code is doing and to change it to do what you need.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I have edited my questions and put my efforts above, can you please have a quick look? Really appreciated

Comment: You've just dumped the code from the answer I linked. As I said, SO is NOT a free code writing service. **Make an effort to modify it yourself to fit your needs.**

Comment: Note that you made an error transcribing that A. `directory = "C:\XXXX"` should be `directory = "C:\XXXX\"`

Comment: @chrisneilsen I added that back slash and ran the code again, still, nothing happened, I was wondering where the files will be generated?